# Visual Studio Code - Center the screen on line (no-addons)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am constantly trying to improve my software skills, mostly by using some powerful shortcuts.

I can move the screen up and down using CTRL+ ARROW_DOWN or ARROW_UP

But how can i put the line i'm working on in the center in one tap ?

Aand because reasons, i can only use vanilla Visual Studio Code.

Thanks for reading !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not possible with a vanilla copy of Visual Studio Code. As per harrymc's (now deleted) comment, there's a addon called [center editor window](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kaiwood.center-editor-window) that makes this possible.